# I want to have SSL certificate on google cloud function trigger link and also add HSTS header into the response headers, how can I do that?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, tls1.2, hsts

In our project we are using cloud functions to do some tasks, but the trigger url of those cloud functions are not secured properly.

Error Points:-

1. TLS version 1.0 and 1.1 are enabled.
2. HSTS(HTTPS Strict Transport Security) header is missing from response

Solution we want:-

1. TLS version should be greater than or equal to TLS 1.2  preferably TLS 1.3
2. HSTS response header added into the response which we are receiving from Cloud functions

Questions are in relation to Google Cloud Platform, Cloud Functions

Comment: 1) TLS: You do not have the ability to control the TLS versions (policy) supported for Cloud Functions. You can deploy an HTTP(S) Load Balancer and control the TLS Policy for the frontend, but not the Cloud Functions backend. 2) HSTS: I have not tested this, but I believe you can add the HSTS header in your Cloud Functions HTTP response. 3) I recommend that you split your question into two questions to assist with better answers.

Comment: Can we have a single Load balancer for all the cloud functions?

Comment: You can have one endpoint per Serverless NEG. I believe there is a hard limit of 50 Serverless NEG backends. Consult the documentation to ensure your use case is supported: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless AND https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#backends